# Docusign: Disable preformatted style signature and allow user to ONLY draw or upload their signature

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

Hi I would like to know if docusign have a way to disable preformatted style signature, and only allow the user to draw their signature or upload the signature.

I've tried to do this

```
let signer1 = docusign.Signer.constructFromObject({
                email: args.envelopeArgs.signerEmail,
                name: args.envelopeArgs.signerName,
                clientUserId: args.envelopeArgs.signerClientId,
                recipientId: 1,
                signInEachLocation: "true",
                requireUploadSignature: "true"
            });
```

but I got an error. Is there a solution?

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reaching out to us. Unfortunately the two systems you're trying to invoke are not compatible -- SignInEachLocation and RequireUpload signature cannot be used at the same time in an API call.

The easiest way to do this would be at the account level under Signing Settings -> Signature Adoption Configuration. If you only have the boxes checked for disabling style selection then drawing / uploading a signature should be the only options left.

If you don't have access to this feature feel free to reach out to Customer Support, it is a free feature that can be activated by a CS rep on your behalf.

Regards,

Matt